# which of these fields will cure aging?

Tags: molecular-biology, senescence, gene-therapy, regeneration

life extension is expected to happen as a result of breakthroughs in tissue rejuvenation, stem cells, regenerative medicine, molecular repair, gene therapy, pharmaceuticals, and organ replacement. Which among the seven fields is more likely to achieve that goal in the foreseeable future?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as opinion based. It's an interesting question for discussion, but doesn't fit the SE model.

Comment: Not even opinion based, as any answer would require a crystal ball :-)

Comment: If we knew that, then we'd just emphasize research in that area, and reduce the effort in the other areas. Qualified opinions in the matter differ, and in the end they could all be wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the structure of this question could be less opinion based as De Novo stated above. But a recent article published by mayo clinic will help shed light on the question. Falls under the category of regenerative medicine I believe.

[Senolytics Article](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41591-018-0092-9)

EDIT:
 Since links are apparently a taboo, here is the paper. Educational on current research and methods on an 'aging cure'.

Xu, Ming, et al. "Senolytics improve physical function and increase lifespan in old age." Nature medicine (2018): 1.

Comment: We frown upon link-only answers at StackExchange as a whole and here at Bio specifically because they are likely to degrade over time and not exist anymore, making your answer meaningless. However, I would also consider whether this question should be answered at all, since fortune telling is not all that scientific.